# Dropdown button not working on some pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hover

We built our website using Adobe Muse, which has since become obsolete, but since beginning to manually amend the code outside of Adobe Muse, the dropdown button on our navbar has decided to stop working on some pages.

Please see the '**Depots**' button on the below URL:

https://stc-uk.com/dropdown.html

When hovering, a list of our depots is displayed.

The same code is present on the below page, but the button doesn't do anything when hovering:

https://stc-uk.com/stc.html

We have tried to copy and paste the code but this doesn't work.

It's not a simple html/css dropdown button, as we generated the button through an Adobe Muse widget. We've tried to re-create the button just using html/css but it doesn't fit in correctly.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show some code, not a link to another site. The editor is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Pardon the blunt feedback, but that site badly needs to be rebuilt. It has very dated design and isn't mobile-friendly. It's not even slightly-smaller-screen friendly, requiring over 1300px of width to avoid ugly horizontal scroll. And it has severe accessibility issues (lack of keyboard navigability, text as images, etc.). Bite the bullet, friend.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).